Chrome Extension Allow Site to Bypass Partitioned Storage
I'm creating a Chrome Extension and one feature relies on being able to iframe a 3rd party website. I'm modifying the headers to allow the site to be iframed but I'm running into issues because the site isn't able to access its stored data in local storage - which causes the site to assume the user is logged out instead of displaying the logged in state.
Is there a way that I can allow a site to access unpartitioned storage via a chrome extension API?

This should happen automatically when you do it inside an extension page, so it must be a bug in Chrome.
